# asp.net mvc Get current property attribute value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes

Is it possible to access the display name of a associated property in other attribute? for example, say I defined a class as

```
public class Test
{
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [MyAttribute()]
    public string SomeProperty {get;set;}

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    [MyAttribute()]
    public string SomeOtherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

I want to access Display Name in MyAttribute without manually writing property name

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand, why do you need another attribue for it. Sample code could be:

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public static string GetAttribute(MemberInfo m)
    {
        var displayName =(DisplayNameAttribute)Attribute
                               .GetCustomAttribute(m, typeof(DisplayNameAttribute));

        return displayName.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

With usage:

```
//First Name
var firstName= MyAttribute.GetAttribute(typeof(Test)
                     .GetMember(nameof(Test.SomeProperty)).First());
//Last Name
var lastName = MyAttribute.GetAttribute(typeof(Test)
                    .GetMember(nameof(Test.SomeOtherProperty)).First());
```

**UPDATE**  If you just want, that you `MyAttribute` always has property set the same as `DisplayName`, you could do something like this:

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public MyAttribute([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        Display = ((DisplayNameAttribute)GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Test).GetMember(propertyName).First(), typeof(DisplayNameAttribute))).DisplayName;
    }
}
```